# Magento: Add New Product Form not displaying in Admin

Tags: forms, magento, admin, product

I've just installed the magento and when I tried to add new product from admin,But  now product form is not being displaying. I can see the page like this

[image]

what should I do? Please, I searched through Google, but, couldn't find any appropriate answer.

Comment: Did you check to see if you have any js error in your console?

Comment: please check first go catalog->attributes->Manage Attribute Sets there have any default attribute list or not

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to clear cache and cookies? also some times you have to do it on the shell on /path/to/my/magento/folder/var/cache just run "rm -fr *".

If that doesn't work you can check you files ownership and permissions (the http service has to have the write write permissions an ownership on the files and folder - http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions).

Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try enabling display_errors in index.php i.e.

## ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Also you could enable logs in your backend, and check for errors in system.log and exception.log

As Magneto's back end makes heavy use of prototype.js, check your console for errors .